# ASP .Net Identity and Entity Framework Database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm developing an event page using entity framework and asp net identity 2.0 and I'm new also with this kind of tools.

If I create a new project that using template visual studio, it's automatically create a DB with several table. and also there are many code that I don't need in that template. (template -> project mvc with already installed authentication).

I've read several tutorial, but for creating from scratch my step is like this :

1. Create a DB
2. Create simple mvc project and install package nuget for asp net identity and EF framework
3. Set the connection strings
4. Create the code and EF will automatically created the table if not exist on DB?

I'm not really sure with number 4.. and are my steps are correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the tutorial step by step, this will teach you how to create and build your project in a very simple way.

**Getting started with ASP.NET Identity:**

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/Customizing-the-ASPNET-Identity-Data-Model-with-the-Entity-Framework-Fluent-API--Part-1

and here is a good **Introduction to ASP.NET Identity:**

http://tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-identity-tutorial-basics/